# Detailed Instruction on how to make virtual packages

Tags: package-management

The problem is that I have vanilla TeXlive installed from the internet. However when I want to install a program like LyX, it says this:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dvipng latex-beamer latex-xcolor lmodern lyx lyx-common pgf
  preview-latex-style prosper ps2eps tex-common texlive-base texlive-binaries
  texlive-common texlive-doc-base texlive-extra-utils texlive-font-utils
  texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-fonts-recommended-doc
  texlive-generic-extra texlive-generic-recommended texlive-latex-base
  texlive-latex-base-doc texlive-latex-extra texlive-latex-extra-doc
  texlive-latex-recommended texlive-latex-recommended-doc texlive-pictures
  texlive-pictures-doc texlive-pstricks texlive-pstricks-doc texlive-science
  texlive-science-doc tipa
```

I'm sure that `latex-beamer`, `latex-xcolor` and other ones installed as I have a full installation. The question is how to make a virtual package system-wide from what I have already on my computer. Ubuntu should detect and recognize it as an installed package. Also the package should be updated when I forinstance use `tlmgr update --all`. Could someone shed some light on this issue?

Comment: How you installed latex beamer? From source?

Comment: @Tachyons, no from CTAN Texlive

Comment: I am not familiar with tex, so Idk about risk of skipping it. Any way you can create a empty debian package with name latex beamer using dpkg -b. I will post detailed instructions later if no other ppl answered this question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu only knows about its package system. It isn't going to integrate with CTAN's. If you want to trick APT into thinking that you have Ubuntu versions of these packages, you have to do that yourself. And it probably won't work perfectly.

You can use the `equivs` package to easily make a package that `Provides` all of these packages. That should work.